# push_san() missing 1 required positional argument: 'san'

Tags: python, python-chess

I am using the python-chess modal
Input: list called 'pre' containing: ['e2e4','e7e5']

```html
for x in range(0, len(pre)-1):
        move=chess.Move.from_uci(str(pre[x]))
        print(move)
        board.push_san(move())
    print(board)
```

The error:
TypeError: push_san() missing 1 required positional argument: 'san'

Any ideas on fixing this issue? thx

Comment: Have you tried changing `board.push_san(move())` to `board.push_san(move)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
for x in pre:                             #range(0, len(pre)-1) is useless
    move=chess.Move.from_uci(x).          #str() is useless : pre contains only strings
    print(move)
    board.push_san(move)                  # move, not move()
print(board)
```